# Is there a scroller component for Android?

Tags: android, scroller

I just wanna know if anybody knows a good reference to something similiar to :

[image: Image Scroller]

But for Android.

or I need to implement by myself ?

Comment: AFAIK, you should custom it yourself

Comment: I think I will use the coverflow example and do some customization like rotate it to be a horizontal. I still don'[t know the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may want to check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html, customize it and implement a custom view for the items

Comment: Ok, how to make it vertical ! like list view with the same animation ?

Comment: it should work by setting the orientation android:orientation="vertical".

Answer (score 2):

Here is one example like it.. but more beautiful
http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/01/android-coverflow-widget.html

Comment: its cool but I still need the animation ! I know that I can make a listview with custom layouts ( row ) but I need the animation or the behave of the gallery or anything else !